# Unexpected behavior using iterators with nested vectors

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, c++11

This sample program gets an iterator to an element of a vector contained in another vector. I add another element to the containing vector and then print out the value of the previously obtained iterator:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > foo(3, std::vector<int>(3, 1));
    std::vector<int>::iterator foo_it = foo[0].begin();
    std::cout << "*foo_it: " << *foo_it << std::endl;
    foo.push_back(std::vector<int>(3, 2));
    std::cout << "*foo_it: " << *foo_it << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since the vector correspinding to `foo_it` has not been modified I expect the iterator to still be valid. However when I run this code I get the following output (also on [ideone](http://ideone.com/hYWdV)):

```
*foo_it: 1
*foo_it: 0
```

For reference I get this result using g++ versions 4.2 and 4.6 as well as clang 3.1. However I get the expected output with g++ using `-std=c++0x` ([ideone link](http://ideone.com/zXQs9)) and also with `clang` when using both `-std=c++0x` and  `-stdlib=libc++`.

Have I somehow invoked some undefined behavior here? If so is this now defined behavior C++11? Or is this simply a compiler/standard library bug?

**Edit** I can see now that in C++03 the iterators are invalidated since the vector's elements are copied on reallocation. However I would still like to know if this would be valid in C++11 (i.e. are the vector's elements guaranteed to be moved instead of copied, and will moving a vector not invalidate it's iterators).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`push_back` invalidates iterators, simple as that.

```
std::vector<int>::iterator foo_it = foo[0].begin();
foo.push_back(std::vector<int>(3, 2));
```

After this, `foo_ti` is no longer valid. Any insert/push_back has the potential to internally re-allocate the vector.

Comment: And also invalidates any pointers or references to the vector's elements, such as those obtained by `operator[]`.

Comment: He's not calling `push_back` on the `vector` he got the iterator from.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore he calles `foo[0].begin()`, then `push_back` on `foo`, not `foo[0]`

Comment: @SethCarnegie: The outer vector's `push_back` is allowed to copy it's internal elements around, and the copied vector's iterators do not match the source vector's iterators. (Then, after the outer vector has reallocated, the original vectors are destroyed, which invalidates the iterators) It works with `-std=c++0x` because the inner vectors get moved rather than copied.

Comment: @BillyONeal ah, that was what I was expecting then, for them to be moved.

Comment: So would this be undefined behavior in C++03, but now is defined behavior in C++11?

Comment: @DavidBrown: I believe that would be the case, yes.

Comment: @DavidBrown: Consider that std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> is okay, which would not be the case if C++11 admitted any other behavior (because you *can't* copy unique_ptr s)

Comment: @BillyONeal So it's guaranteed to move then. It would still be nice to know that iterators aren't invalidated when you move a vector. I've found a quote saying they aren't when using `swap` (`§23.2.1/8`) but I have been unable to find something similar for move constructors.

Answer (score 5):

> Since the vector correspinding to `foo_it` has not been modified

Wrong. The `push_back` destroyed the vector corresponding to `foo_it`. `foo_it` became invalid when  `foo[0]` was destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the misperception is that vector< vector < int > > is a vector of pointers and when the outer one is reallocated, the pointers to the inner ones are still valid which is true for **int. But instead, reallocating the vector also reallocates all inner vectors, which makes the inner iterator invalid as well.

Comment: Not always true. (And in fact always false in C++11)

Comment: I tested this by printing out the address of the two values, and they are the same. This means the data from the inner vectors has been reallocated, right?

Comment: That depends on what address you're talking about. The thing though is that in C++11, `std::vector` has to move it's innards (rather than copy) when possible, and a move operation does not invalidate iterators or cause reallocation.

Comment: @Billy - What? If an object is moved to a new place, surely an iterator to the original is now invalid.

Comment: @Bo: The iterator just points to the moved item. (Using vectors as the example, the move operation moves the memory pointer from one vector object to another, but the iterators are pointers into that memory block -- and that block was not modified by the move at all)